# merge array items become single item in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

how to merge array items become single item in ruby ?

if i have case like this :

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

how to get result like this :

```
a = 123
```

thanks before

Comment: Use [`Array#join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-join), like this: `[1, 2, 3].join.to_i`

Comment: Note: `[1,[2,[3,4],[5]]].join.to_i #=> 12345`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` will build a string out of each element in the array. convert that to what you want using `to_i`:

```
[1, 2, 3].join.to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the elements of a collection into a new value, is called "folding" or "reducing", in Ruby, the method that is used for folding is called `Enumerable#inject`. This is a perfect usecase for it:

```
[1, 2, 3].reverse.each_with_index.inject(0) {|acc, (el, i)| acc + el * 10**i }
# => 123
```